# Square view grid using UIStackView - iOS

Tags: ios, swift, stackview

I'm trying to create a grid using UIStackView, I'm able to do it expect for one problem. i can not make it a perfect square. whenever i set aspect ratio constraint i get conflicts constraints.

the grid is 5✕7

I'm embedding each row in a UIStackView, then all the rows in an outer UIStackView but it doesn't seem to work.

what is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Generally, the best way is to use as few constraints as possible. In this case, if your row stack views and the outer stack view are both set to `fill equally` then the only additional constraint should be to set the ratio of the outer stack view to 5:7. Obviously, you will also need some constraints for the overall size and position.